# <span> and <a> tags not aligning vertically

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I am trying to create links for following on Facebook, twitter etc. using a sprite image. There is a plain text following links made up of these sprite images set as background. I am having problem aligning the text, the span and the 'a' links vertically.

Here is the css

```
.sprite a {
    border:solid 1px blue;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#00f;
    background:url('images/sprite.png') 0 0;
}

span {
    border: solid 1px red;
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="sprite">
    Follow us on: <span id="spriteFacebook"><a href="http://facebook.com"></a></span>
</div>
```

I am using borders just to identify the misalignment

This is how the result looks like

[image: preview image of the problem]

Shouldn't these be aligned by default? Should I use floating divs to achieve this?

Comment: Set `vertical-align: middle;` to `.sprite a ` selector

Comment: _“Shouldn't these be aligned by default?”_ – no, because you have an `inline-block` inside an `inline` element here. And what’s the `span` element good for anyway – seems redundant (at least with the little actual formatting you have shown).

Comment: Thanks @RahilWazir for the simple solution!

Comment: Thanks @CBroe for the explanation. The span element I agree is redundant here.

I appreciate both of you for your expert comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:
- wrap a span around your text: `<span class="text">Follow us on:</span>` 
- float it left and give it a line height: `span.text { float: left; line-height: 33px; }`

http://jsfiddle.net/6s4HM/20/

Comment: This works perfectly too... thanks for taking the time.